# Sensitivity to total variance for an option

Tags: variance, total

In the famous [article](https://jod.pm-research.com/content/6/4/9.abstract) of Demertifi, Derman et al (1999), the authors, in the appendix, show that it it necessary to have options weighted inversely proportional to the Square of the Strike in order to have a constant vega in a portfolio of options. $O(S,K,v)$ represents a standard Black-Scholes option of strike $K$ and of total variance $v = \sigma^2t$ when the stock price is $S$.

To show that, the authors start by deriving the sensitivity $V_O$ to the total variance  of an individual option.

And then, they write the following equation:

$$
V_O = t \frac{\delta}{\delta v}(O) 
$$

I do not understand why there is a $t$ in front of the derivative $\frac{\delta}{\delta v}(O)$.

Comment: There are various small variations in definition of vega, for example $\partial / \partial \sigma$, or $\partial / \partial \sigma^2$, or even $\partial / \partial \sigma \sqrt{\tau}$. In Derman's paper he defines vega as $\partial / \partial \sigma^2 = t \partial / \partial (\sigma^2 t)$ $= t\partial / \partial v$

Comment: I agree with you. Then, it means that here, it is not the sensitivity to the total variance but just to the variance. I am quite surprise that it is possible to find a typo in such a famous paper,